Indexing a `HashMap<&String, V>` with `&str`
What is the proper way to index into a HashMap<&String, V> with a &str? Rust reports that &String is not Borrow<str>, which is required for indexing. (This seems a bit silly to me; if T: Borrow<U> then surely &T: Borrow<U> should also hold?)
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let strings = vec!["x".to_owned(), "y".to_owned(), "z".to_owned()];
    let m = [0, 1, 2]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| (&strings[i], i))
        .collect::<HashMap<&String, usize>>();
    let zero = m["x"];
}

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&String: Borrow<str>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |     let zero = m["x"];
  |                  ^^^ the trait `Borrow<str>` is not implemented for `&String`, which is required by `HashMap<&String, usize>: Index<&_>`
  |
  = help: the trait `Borrow<str>` is implemented for `String`
  = help: for that trait implementation, expected `String`, found `&String`
  = note: required for `HashMap<&String, usize>` to implement `Index<&str>`

Obviously, because I constructed this particular HashMap, I could go back and change its key type to &str instead. But supposing I'm handed a HashMap<&String, V>, what is the proper way to index it? Constructing a whole String just to take a reference to it seems wasteful.

Do you have a particular performance benchmark reason not to create an owned copy? The compiler is pretty smart on these things.

T: U does not always imply &T: U. Notably, if U contains any methods that take self or &mut self then this would not be possible.

@BrianA.Henning If the HashMap holds a reference to the string then it can't be modified, so no risk there. @cdhowie, I'm talking specifically about the Borrow trait — its requirements are that you an provide a reference without changing the outcomes of Hash, Ord, Eq, which it seems like would apply to &T as well if T: Borrow<U> (and those traits only have reference-taking methods).

With #![feature(hash_raw_entry)], it is possible to access keys directly by hash (with a followup check for equality), which lets one get around borrowing limitations.
#![feature(hash_raw_entry)]

use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher, BuildHasher};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let strings = vec!["x".to_owned(), "y".to_owned(), "z".to_owned()];
    let m = [0, 1, 2]
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| (&strings[i], i))
        .collect::<HashMap<&String, usize>>();
    
    let key = "x";

    let mut hasher = m.hasher().build_hasher();
    key.hash(&mut hasher);
    let hash = hasher.finish();
    
    let zero = m.raw_entry().from_hash(hash, |found_key| found_key == &key);
    println!("{zero:?}");
    // Some(("x", 0))
}


There is a way around this if you are willing to dip into unsafe waters.
This solution takes advantage of the fact that if you have a struct S marked #[repr(transparent)] and containing a single field of type T, you can safely transmute from &'a T to &'b S where 'a: 'b.  (This is why you can borrow a &Path from a PathBuf even though no Path ever actually exists, for example.)
So, let's build a newtype that we can borrow from String, and with a positively bikesheddable name.
#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct StrRef(str);

This definition allows us to safely transmute from &str to &StrRef, so we'll wrap that bit of unsafe code up in a From implementation:
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for &'a StrRef {
    fn from(value: &'a str) -> &'a StrRef {
        // SAFETY: StrRef is repr(transparent) and contains only a str.
        unsafe { &*(value as *const str as *const StrRef) }
    }
}

Now we can implement Borrow<StrRef> on any type from which we can get a &str.
// Not actually needed, just for example.
impl Borrow<StrRef> for String {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &StrRef {
        self.as_str().into()
    }
}

// This is the impl you need in this case.
impl Borrow<StrRef> for &String {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &StrRef {
        self.as_str().into()
    }
}

Finally, this allows us to write the following function, which accomplishes your goal of fetching from the map using a &str without converting it to an owned String:
fn get_from_map<'a, T>(map: &'a HashMap<&String, T>, key: &str) -> Option<&'a T> {
    map.get(<&StrRef>::from(key))
}

(Playground)
Obviously, if you can change the map's key type to &str then you should prefer that, but if you don't have control over where the map comes from then this is a viable workaround (in a -- hopefully -- very limited scope within your program).

Fantastic answer, I'm bookmarking it. It does use unsafe, but unsafe is limited to a single easily verifiable line, and accomplishes the effect that more than makes up for it. Now for the naming bikeshed (the actual reason for writing this comment): since StrRef doesn't contain an actual reference, but serves to interoperate with hashmap keys, I'd go for StrKey or StrLookup.

@user4815162342 Yep, the name is bad for sure, but is also the least interesting part of the answer and easily refactored so I gave it very little thought, focusing on the rest instead. :)

Do you think the approach from this answer can be generalized to other situations, such as lookup in HashMap<(String, String), T> given a (&str, &str)? I tried the obvious extension, but the compiler isn't happy with a struct TwoStr(str, str).

@user4815162342 This exact approach doesn't, but you're in luck -- I've answered that one before. There's a fair bit more unsafe but it works.

I think the ability to do this is why I felt that it was silly that &String is not Borrow<str> — it's obvious that &String is the right “shape” to be borrowed and provide a &str, but implementing the trait is just not allowed within the type system due to the blanket impl applying to both &String and String. (Maybe specialization could fix this?)

@BallpointBen I think std could in fact provide an implementation, it just doesn't. There's also the question of how many reference layers to implement for, which you could argue for any trait.

Ah, right you are. I'd argue that if possible, traits should be implemented for one layer of references, because it's always possible to turn N references into 1 (right?), but it's not necessarily possible to turn 1 into 0.

@cdhowie I've now taken a look at the previous answer, and unfortunately it doesn't do what I alluded to. In that answer the HashMap itself has a different type - it's not HashMap<(String, String), T> or even HashMap<[String; 2], T>, it's HashMap<Key, T>. While the answer is still technically impressive, it doesn't address the same limitation as this one, because this one does its magic without modifying the type of the HashMap (which is often supplied by code we don't control).

@user4815162342 Right. I don't think there's a way around that, because there aren't layout guarantees for tuples the same way there are for arrays. There isn't a safe way to transmute a &(String, String) into something useful in that case. I guess that answer is more useful for the general case of "I need a two-string key."

impl<U, T: Borrow<U>> Borrow<U> for &T {

conflicts with the existing
impl<T> Borrow<T> for T {

so it can't be added.
Playground
When you're in control you shouldn't use &String as keys to begin with. The preferred way would be to use &str which can trivially be created from a &String and you don't have the problem and is more general.
When you're not in control creating a String just to index is your only safe option.
